# iOS: UITextField in UITableViewCell that calls method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield, parse-server

I need to use a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell`. This is using Parse open source and I want it to send back a title. So when it calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it needs to do something like this.

```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
    {
      static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
      UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
      UITextField *TextField = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:284];

      [TextField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
      [TextField addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(TitleTextFieldFinished:indexPath:object:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

      TextField.text = [object objectForKey:@"Toppingname"];

      return cell;

    }
```

Then it might be called like this:

```
- (void)TitleTextField:(UITextField *)TextField:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:(PFObject *)object
{

  [TextField resignFirstResponder];
  PFQuery *item = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"className"];
  [item getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.menuid
                              block:^(PFObject *title, NSError *error) {
                                NSString *newTitle = @"New title";
                                title[@"title"] = newTitle;
                                [title saveInBackground];

                              }];
}
```

If any one could help that would be great!

Comment: FYI - it is standard practice that method and variable names start with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase letters. Following this standard makes your code a lot easier to read by others.

Comment: Also, you should avoid Objective-C method names with anonymous parameter names. Your proposed text field handler is named `TitleTextField::`. This naming convention combined with a lack of whitespace makes your code very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation can be like as below

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *) [cell viewWithTag:284];

    [textField setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [textField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(titleTextField:inIndexPath:forObject:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];

    textField.text = @"Sandeep";

    return cell;
}


- (void)titleTextField:(UITextField *)textField inIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forObject:(PFObject *)object {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

But you will not get the "indexPath" and "object" value because sender(UITextField) didn't know about which indexPath and which object it should send.

Comment: No, you can't do anything like this. The `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method only accepts selectors with 0, 1, or 2 parameters and they can't be of arbitrary types. This will likely crash.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` method, the method is only allowed a very limited and fixed option for the possible parameters. It must either take no parameters, 1 parameter (the control), or 2 parameters (the control and the event).

You are attempting to pass two completely unrelated parameters. Plus, due to your strange method naming convention, your method name doesn't actually match what you put in `@selector`.

You will have to determine the `indexPath` inside the action method based on the text field and you will have to use another means (such as an instance variable) to get access to the `PFObject`.

And unless you are using something added by Parse (I'm not familiar with it), the method signature for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is incorrect. It doesn't have a `PFObject` parameter normally.